# Brute forcing password on an OpenSSL encoded file

Tags: openssl

I have a file encoded using the following

```
echo "secret" | openssl enc -aes256 -salt -out file.enc -e -a -pbkdf2 -k 'PASSWORD'
```

I am using https://github.com/glv2/bruteforce-salted-openssl with the rockyou list. Nothing coming up so just wanted to check syntax

```
bruteforce-salted-openssl -f rockyou.txt flag_decoded.enc -1 -v 1 -c aes256
```

Does that look right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The tool you are trying to leverage uses the deprecated method `EVP_BytesToKey()` to derive the key from the salt and the passphrase, see [line 425](https://github.com/glv2/bruteforce-salted-openssl/blob/1.4.2/src/bruteforce-salted-openssl.c#L425). If your encryption used a different kind of key derivation, like you did with the `-pbkdf2` option, the tool will not be able to find the passphrase used.

Additionally, the `EVP_BytesToKey()` function takes a digest algorithm that was `md5` by default for older versions of OpenSSL and is `sha-256` for the current version of OpenSSL. The tool assumes md5 so depending on which version you are using, you may have to indicate which digest to use.

Finally, the `-a` option that you provided during encryption results in a base64-encoded output file, which the tool is not able to deal with either.

Keeping that in mind, you can see it working like this, after removing the `-a` and `-pbkdf2` options when encrypting and indicating to the tool to use `sha256`:

```
$ echo "secret" | openssl enc -aes256 -salt -out file.enc -e -k PASSWORD
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
$ ./bruteforce-salted-openssl -f rockyou.txt -d sha256 -1 -v 1 -c aes256 file.enc 
Warning: using dictionary mode, ignoring options -b, -e, -l, -m and -s.

Tried passwords: 798
Tried passwords per second: inf
Last tried password: PASSWORD

Password candidate: PASSWORD
```